# Importing specific data from csv file into MS Access

Tags: csv, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a csv file that's an output from a tool and I need to read specific data from this file (just B3 and thenfrom A13 to C17, it will always be the same). After that it needs to be imported into an ms access table. Is there a function I can use to do this that I can then set behind a button so its user friendly?

Comment: _A13 to C17_ is an Excel range. A csv file is basically a text file. If all you need is a specific range in Excel, you can convert the csv to excel, and import (or link to) the range. Otherwise, you nust import the entire csv.

Comment: Probably the more easy solution (instead of converting it to a spreadsheet, then importing specific columns from there) is just to use `DoCmd.TransferText` to import the entire sheet, and then either delete the unneeded columns or copy the needed columns to a table and delete the old table.

Answer (score 0):

After you convert the file to Excel (SaveAs -> Excel Workbook), use this line of code *behind a button* to Import the data to Access:

```
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9,  YourTableName, YourFileName, False, "B3"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acLink, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9,  YourTableName, YourFileName, False, "A13:C17"
```

Once the data is in Access, you can do anything with it.
Please find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Access-VBA/articles/docmd-transferspreadsheet-method-access) assistance on the `TransferSpreadsheet` Function.

You can use the `Excel.Application` Object to convert csv to Excel by code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply I've got my code working to the point where it takes a csv file and converts it to a excel file and starts to import it the problem is defining each cell the format you gave gives an error saying "B3" cannot be found. I looked around on here and saw a similar post that said to try naming the range then calling it but can't find anything to this from the access side is this possible or is there a way to reference a cell without naming it? Thanks  again for the advice so far